# Стилизация скроллбара в пределах одного дива

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть селект (для него используется плагин select2). Как стилизировать скроллбар внутри него таким образом, чтобы стили не применялись ко всей странице?

Попробовал использовать для этих целей плагин [SimpleScrollbar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar), но добиться требуемого результата не удалось.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

$('body').on('select2:open', function () {
  var el = document.querySelector('.select2-results__options');
  SimpleScrollbar.initEl(el);
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

кроссбраузерность только хромает, но как вариант могу предложить так:
**P.S.:** С учетом, что только один `select-select2` на странице. Если больше, то они все будут иметь такой scroll.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 200px !important;
  margin-left: 15px
}
.sss {
  width: 200px !important;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 15px
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
}
.select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.44, rgb(122, 153, 217)), color-stop(0.72, rgb(73, 125, 189)), color-stop(0.86, rgb(28, 58, 148)));
}
.mul::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.mul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.mul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #99f5fc 0%, #ffa8f9 50%, #9fb8ef 51%, #2ac0ed 100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">

  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>

</select>
<select class="sss">
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>

<div class='mul'>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот, например, используя плагин SlimScroll. Скачать и документация - http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
  
  $(".js-example-basic-single").on('select2:open', function () {
     $('.select2-results__options').slimScroll();
  });

});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.8/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```